# Conditional Formatting Hides Text

Tags: c#, excel, format

I have an Excel worksheet which I'm adding conditional formatting to from an add-in written in C#.

The condition fires ok and I'm able to change the fill colour but the text always gets hidden.

If I remove the fill colour from the format, the text still gets hidden when the formatting is applied.

If I remove all the formatting and just apply the condition without any format changes, the text is still hidden.

When the format condition is no longer valid, the text appears as you would expect.

The cell value is definitely set correctly.

Why would this happen?

C# code as follows:

```
var disabledFormat = "IF(blah blah...),FALSE,TRUE)";
var formatCondition = (Excel.FormatCondition)cell.FormatConditions.Add(
                           Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, 
                           Type.Missing, disabledFormat);
formatCondition.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C0C0C0");
formatCondition.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F0F0F0");
```

[Edit]

I have tried changing the colour to white, black, red etc. but it is still invisible when the conditional formatting applies.

[/Edit]

[Edit2]

Full disabledFormat string as requested:
(The code does not look exactly link this as it spans several classes, I've just tried to fill-in the blanks to be helpful :$)

```
const string FORMAT_DISABLED = "=IF(LEFT(MID('{2}'!{0},FIND(\"|\",'{2}'!{0},FIND(\"|\",'{2}'!{0})+1)+1,999),LEN(INDIRECT(\"'$lookup_grading'!\"&ADDRESS({1},1))))=INDIRECT(\"'$lookup_grading'!\"&ADDRESS({1},1)),FALSE,TRUE)";

var dropdownCell = "Q5";

var disabledFormat = string.Format(FORMAT_DISABLED, cellName, dropdownCell, controlSheetName);
```

Resolves to:

```
=IF(LEFT(MID('$controls_Distribution Grid'!W19,FIND("|",'$controls_Distribution Grid'!W19,FIND("|",'$controls_Distribution Grid'!W19)+1)+1,999),LEN(INDIRECT("'$lookup_grading'!"&ADDRESS(Q5,1))))=INDIRECT("'$lookup_grading'!"&ADDRESS(Q5,1)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

To try to clarify further, what this does is it looks up a value in a cell in another worksheet with the same address, grabs a value from a formatted string in that cell and compares it to the value indicated by the selected item in a dropdown. If there is a match `TRUE` is returned.

The same formula is also used to return `1` or `0` for the cell value so I know this works ok.

[/Edit2]

[Edit3]

I've narrowed the problem down to the `NumberFormat`, which is `"a";;;`.
When the conditional formatting does not trigger this correctly shows `a` (or a tick with Webdings applied).
But when the conditional formatting triggers the output from the NumberFormat does not appear.
I can't think why this would be intentional so I'm guessing this is a bug in Excel, but I'll do some Googling to check

[/Edit3]

This is the formula in the cell which returns a 1 or 0 (hope it's clear enough!):

```
=IF(
    LEFT(
        MID('$controls_Distribution Grid'!$V$19,
            FIND("|",'$controls_Distribution Grid'!$V$19,
                FIND("|",'$controls_Distribution Grid'!$V$19)+1
            )+1,999),
        LEN(INDIRECT("'$lookup_grading'!"&ADDRESS(Q5,1)))
    )=INDIRECT("'$lookup_grading'!"&ADDRESS(Q5,1)),
1,0)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's hidden and not just the same colour? (or a very similar colour that makes it look hidden)

Comment: No, either could be true. But setting the font colour to anything makes no difference. If I over-type the cell I can see the text while typing but it disappears when I leave the cell.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the font colour is not the same. The problem still occurs if I don't change any colours.

Comment: Can you show the actual `disabledFormat` string?  And are those the only 2 `formatConditions` you have?

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it will be but I've supplied the code to construct the `disabledFormat` string, plus an example of how it looks when constructed.

Comment: And yes, those are the only 2 `formatConditions`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with vb.net but couldn't. However I noticed that your condition didn't work for me as I had to put a "=" in front of the IF. So e.g. I used this condition  "=IF(1<0;FALSE;TRUE)". I also had to use ";" as separator. Maybe you can give it a try to see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: Just going into a meeting but will try that! Thanks :)

Comment: Mine already had an `=` sign, it just didn't make it into my example above. Also, Excel throws an exception if I use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: I use semicolon as delimiter because in my regional settings I have it defined as list separator  (french config). Did you check directly in Excel the resulting rule: is the font format set correctly?

Comment: Good question, but yes I have. The font is set fine and the text is visible if the rule does not trigger. But if the rule triggers and the fill colour changes, the text becomes invisible.

Comment: What are the cell's Format? General, Custom, Numeric? They aren't a triple semi-colon are they? **;;;**

Comment: Close - it's `a;;;` (gives a tick in Wingdings)

Comment: Once you have set the formatting via C#, are you then able to go view the conditional formatting as it was implemented in Excel? i.e. go and try and edit the conditional formatting in the Excel file, and see what the resulting text and fill color settings are. (you may have done this, but I wasn't sure)

Comment: Hi, yes I can do that and it looks ok. However I've noticed that text from Number Formatting is not shown when Conditional Formatting is applied, which seems to be the problem here. Trying to find a work-around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a number format is four fields separated by `;`

```
<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
```

Your number format `"a";;;` means if the value is positive display `a` , if it's zero, negative or text display nothing.

Your formula returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which are treated as text, so when your condition fires, the format hides the cell value.

I suggest you change your formula to return `1` or `0` which will then display `a` or nothing

Comment: Actually that is just the condition formula, i.e. the one which determines whether or not the format is applied. The actual cell value is 1 or 0. But thanks for the answer and the lesson on formatting :)

Comment: @bukko so what is the actual cell value?

Comment: 1 or 0 (more letters so S/O will let me post)

Comment: @bukko which value is it when you want to display the `a`, 1, 0 or either?

Comment: 1 should display the `a`. It's actually a formula which I'm just re-running now so I can post it...

Comment: Formula posted. I also changed the format to `"a";;"ERROR";"ERROR"` just in case, but it still looks ok.

Comment: Fixed it. The number formatting was initially wrong but I needed to change it in a few places in code. Once I did that it works great! I wouldn't have got there without your explanation. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
formatCondition.Font.ThemeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#909090");
formatCondition.Interior.ThemeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F0F0F0");
formatCondition.Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic;
```

I don't know if the `PatternColorIndex` is necessary or not, that is what I got from macro recording.

Edit:
this is the macro if that helps you:

```
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
End With
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the `ThemeColor` suggestion. I tried it but the result is the same. The Macro is no good unfortunately as I have to use C# code in an Add-in.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be an error in the font file. Try a standard character A-Z to see it it disappears when formatted. If it doesn't disappear then you could have a corrupt font file. Might have to dump the wingdings font and re-install.

Comment: I used the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager to try to edit the rule, but the font list appears to be disabled so I can't manually change to another font!

Comment: But I think that's normal. However if I manually change the cell font e.g. Tahmoa or Calibri, the text is still invisible.

Comment: If I manually add the same conditional formatting to another cell - i.e. not using C# - all appears fine. It's only a problem when adding conditional formatting by C# code.